# Application hangs for few minutes even after all the threads are done

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I converted a working Producer/Consumer Example from Thread/Runnable to Executor/Callable/BlockingQueues and using the Poison Pill termination pattern.

If you run the program below, it will hang for few minutes even though every thread has completed. 
jstack shows numerous threads blocked on a queue that is not seemingly related to the application.

```
"pool-1-thread-10" prio=5 tid=10b08d000 nid=0x10d91c000 waiting on condition [10d91b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <7f3113510> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:424)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:323)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:874)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:945)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I can not figure out why the application hangs. Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class ProducersConsumers {
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Item> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Item>();
    private static final ExecutorService executorPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private Random randGenerator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    private class Item {
        private boolean done = false;
        private String message;

        private Item(boolean done) {
            this.done = done;
        }

        private Item(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public boolean isDone() {
            return done;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    }

    private class Producer implements Callable<Long> {
        private final int id;
        private Integer numOfMessages;

        private Producer(int id, int numOfMessages) {
            this.id = id;
            this.numOfMessages = numOfMessages;
        }

        @Override
        public Long call() throws Exception {
            long totalTime = 0;
            while (numOfMessages > 0) {
                String message;
                synchronized (numOfMessages) {
                    long starttime = System.nanoTime();
                    int msgLength = randGenerator.nextInt(20000);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(msgLength);
                    for (int a = 0; a < msgLength; a++) {
                        sb.append((char) ('a' + randGenerator.nextInt(26)));
                    }
                    message = sb.toString();
                    long endtime = System.nanoTime();
                    totalTime += endtime - starttime;
                }
                numOfMessages--;
                queue.put(new Item(message));
            }
            System.out.println("-------------Producer " + id + " is done.");
            queue.put(new Item(true));
            return totalTime;
        }
    }

    private class Consumer implements Callable<Long> {
        private String monitor = "monitor";
        private final int id;

        private Consumer(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public Long call() throws Exception {
            long totalTime = 0;
            while (true) {
                Item item = queue.take();
                if (item.isDone()) {
                    break;
                }
                synchronized (monitor) {
                    long starttime = System.nanoTime();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(item.getMessage());
                    sb = sb.reverse();
                    String message = sb.toString();
                    long endtime = System.nanoTime();
                    totalTime += endtime - starttime;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("+++++++++++++Consumer " + id + " is done.");
            return totalTime;
        }
    }

    public void begin(int threadCount) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Collection<Producer> producers = new ArrayList<Producer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            producers.add(new Producer(i, randGenerator.nextInt(5)));
        }
        Collection<Consumer> consumers = new ArrayList<Consumer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            consumers.add(new Consumer(i));
        }
        try {
            long starttime = System.nanoTime();
            List<Future<Long>> producerFutureList = executorPool.invokeAll(producers);
            List<Future<Long>> consumerFutureList = executorPool.invokeAll(consumers);
            long producerTotalTime = 0;
            long consumerTotalTime = 0;

            for (Future<Long> future : producerFutureList) {
                producerTotalTime += future.get();
            }
            for (Future<Long> future : consumerFutureList) {
                consumerTotalTime += future.get();
            }
            long mainThreadTotalTime = System.nanoTime() - starttime;

            System.out.println("producerTotalTime   " + producerTotalTime);
            System.out.println("consumerTotalTime   " + consumerTotalTime);
            System.out.println("mainThreadTotalTime " + mainThreadTotalTime);
            System.out.println("Difference          " + (producerTotalTime + consumerTotalTime - mainThreadTotalTime));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            throw e;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            throw e;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ProducersConsumers prodcon = new ProducersConsumers();
        prodcon.begin(20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should close the ExecutorService when you are done with it. Call executorPool.shutdown() at the end of your program.

Comment: The docs for ExecutorService don't state you need to shutdown when you're done, but the examples do so.

Comment: That was it! Calling shutdown() fixed the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ptomli I know it's been a long time since you made that comment. I thought the same thing at first. But recently, I did find something in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) that supports having to call `shutdown`. They state that *An unused ExecutorService should be shut down to allow reclamation of its resources.* So when you are done with your `ExecutorService`, you should always call `shutdown`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a shared resource, specifically `numOfMessages` outside of a synchronized block.

```
while (numOfMessages > 0) {
    // blah
    synchronized (numOfMessages) {
        // blah
    }
}
```

I don't think this is the cause of your problem, but it's certainly non thread-safe. It's a typical check-then-act scenario. Refer to either [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) or [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) for reasons why this is Not Good (TM).

Comment: numOfMessages is not acting as a synchronized monitor here. As you notice, numOfMessages is object level and therefore no one will access it outside the one thread. The reason, however, for the synchronized block is to indicate to JVM that it should not interrupt this thread while it is executing inside the block in order to record an accurate total time of execution. W/o the block, if the thread is swapped out due to load, then the recorded processing time will include the waiting state phase, hence, inaccurate. Thanks for bringing it up though

Comment: Or you sure this is true? I wrote a sample program and it seems like there are context switches even inside a synchronized block.

Comment: Hmmmm. Not sure now. I thought I learned that many years ago but after you mentioned it, I wasn't able to verify it. Is there away to prevent the scheduler from swapping the thread out during a critical block?

Comment: You should be using java.util.concurrent instead of synchronized